# Risks of allowing users to create links?

Tags: security, web, xss

I'm setting up a web environment where users can create links **but** they can only modify the href attribute, not type in the `<a>` tag themselves.

So basically any href value is allowed; http/ftp/mailto/whatever.

Are there any XSS or other risks for **my** site if I leave the href attribute open like this? If yes, what would they be and how should I handle them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **must** ensure that the href value will be a valid URL. If you would not escaped user input it would make mySQL injection attacks possible.

also the user could enter javascript:

```
<a href="javascript:window.close();">Javascript will close the browser window on click</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

There are URL schemes, such as `javascript:` or possibly `data:`, that could, in themselves, serve as XSS vectors if the user is tricked into clicking them.  You should maintain a **whitelist** of known, safe URL schemes (like `http`, `https`, `ftp`, etc.) and disallow any URLs that don't begin with such a scheme.

Note that simply *blacklisting* known dangerous URL schemes is *not* a safe approach, since you cannot possibly know all the schemes that might be used as attack vectors (as this may depend on things like what third-party software the user has installed).  In particular, keep in mind that URL schemes are supposed to be case-insensitive; a naïve blacklisting implementation that simply disallowed URLs beginning with `javascript:` might be trivially bypassed with a `jAvAsCrIpT:` URL.

(You *could* allow schemeless relative URLs if you wanted, but if so, make sure that you parse them conservatively and [according to the standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986), so that an attacker can't possibly disguise a harmful absolute URL as a relative one.  In particular, I would recommend that any URL that includes a colon (`:`) before the first slash (`/`), if any, be treated as an absolute URL subject to whitelisting.  Just to be sure, you may also want to prepend the string "`./`" to any relative URLs that don't already begin with "`/`" or "`./`" in order to eliminate any potential parsing ambiguity.)

The other thing you need to ensure is that you properly **HTML-escape** any strings, including URLs (*especially* user-supplied ones), that will be embedded in HTML attributes.  In particular, any `&` characters will need to be replaced with the `&amp;` character entity, and (for double-quoted attributes) any `"` characters with `&quot;`.  Replacing `<` with `&lt;` and `'` with `&#39;` may also be a good idea, and the safest approach may be to actually replace *any* characters (other than known safe ones, like alphanumerics) with their corresponding HTML character entities.  In any case, you programming language probably has a standard function or library to do this (e.g. `htmlspecialchars()` in PHP).

**Ps.** See also the [OWASP XSS Filter Evasion Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet) for some examples of possible attacks that your implementation should be able to resist.

Comment: +1 Also the OP should make sure that any local GET links are not vulnerable to CSRF, otherwise a user might enter e.g. "`http://www.example.com/logout`" as their link (where `example.com` is the OP's site).